How to add a User to a Role in a web API with .net8?
I've been trying to add authentication and authorization to my web API using the Auth System provided by .net8 but I'm struggling with the part where I'm supposed to add a User to a Role, for example, when a user sign-in in my app i want to add that user to the Client role, how can i do this without having to rewrite the whole method for register? if there's no other way how can i access to that method to override it?
this is the code that I have, am I missing something?
builder.Services.AddIdentityApiEndpoints<IdentityUser>(opt =>
{
    opt.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
    opt.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    opt.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    opt.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
})
        .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();


So basically we need to seed roles to our database in your Program.cs
 using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var roleManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
    string[] roles = new[] { "superuser", "Client" };
    foreach (var role in roles)
    {
        if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role))
        {
            await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(role));
        }
    }
}

make sure u have added this here,
builder.Services.AddScoped<UserManager<IdentityUser>, CustomUserManager<IdentityUser>>();
    builder.Services.AddIdentityApiEndpoints<IdentityUser>()
     .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
     builder.Services.AddScoped<UserManager<IdentityUser>, CustomUserManager<IdentityUser>>();

and if u see on your database after running the server,

and new we need to assign default roles, like basically by default we only have access to the link to create user so create a c# class name let's say CustomUserManager  and,
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace ReactApp2.Server.Services
{
    public class CustomUserManager<TUser> : UserManager<TUser> where TUser : class
    {
        public CustomUserManager(IUserStore<TUser> store, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor, IPasswordHasher<TUser> passwordHasher,
            IEnumerable<IUserValidator<TUser>> userValidators, IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<TUser>> passwordValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer,
            IdentityErrorDescriber errors, IServiceProvider services, ILogger<UserManager<TUser>> logger)
            : base(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, services, logger)
        {
        }

        public override async Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(TUser user, string password)
        {
            var result = await base.CreateAsync(user, password);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var defaultRole = "Client"; // Change to your default role name
                await AddToRoleAsync(user, defaultRole);
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}

so now if you test your API then as soon as your register someone user with have some role id which is the default role

and here is the user table


Hi, the answer was pretty useful but I have another question, there's a way to override the Confirm Email endpoint? Or any other endpoint? I need to redirect the user to another page when the email is confirmed or display some Html code, thanks in advance

maybe once the boolean of conform email is true on the database you could send json response to the client side something like {conformEmail: true} and based on that response redirect user to your html page

I used to do it like this for email conformation in api using MailKit  ..
   var email = new MimeMessage();
                email.From.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse("your email"));
                email.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse("email of user that you want to send conformation");
                 email.Subject = "Email verification";
                Random module = new Random();
                int code = module.Next(1000, 9999);

                 email.Body = new TextPart(TextFormat.Html)
                 {
                     Text = $"Hi we would like to comform your login your code is: {code}"
                 };

                using var smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
                smtp.Authenticate("your email", "your gmail app password");
                smtp.Send(email);
                smtp.Disconnect(true);  

and later you can create an api to trigger conform email boolean to true or false and based on the result you can redirect user.
